Как найти js файл, который применяется к элементу?
В devtools Chrome хочу найти js файл, который применяется к логотипу на сайте https://www.duten.com/en/. Можно ли его найти, зная только класс .js-letter?

Наверное не файл, а js код? Список js файлов виден в девтулс во вкладке сеть

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Если речь о логотипе, после прелоадера, то в devtools на вкладке Elements методом научного тыка можно пройтись вверх по элементам, начиная от вашего SVG и выше (и выше по необходимости) одновременно глядя на дополнительную панель и её вкладку Event Listeners. В вашем случае вы остановитесь на <a>, где вы заметите событие отвечающее за click и скрипт с ним связанный — npm-luge.js. А кликнув по ссылке рядом с событием окажитесь в начале отработки процесса с ним связанного. Если нужен скрипт из прелоадера, то вам нужно разобраться с "точками останова".

stylok, Благодарю.
